# Copy files from source folder to destination folder based on files in lookup folder

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I'm trying to copy files from one folder to another folder but I only copy the files from source folder if that file exists in lookup folder.

```
@ECHO off
For ℅℅a in (℅1\*) do (
Set file = "℅2\℅℅~na℅℅~xa"
If exist ℅file℅ (
Echo yes
// Copy to destination folder 

)
Else(
Echo no
)
)
```

I am running it like 
"Copy.bat sourcefolder lookupfolder" destinationfolder

I just started batch script today and I Donno what's wrong but I have two folder source folder and look up folder in folder source I placed to files a.txt and b.txt and in folder lookup  I have only b.txt but when I run  its printing yes 2 times although a.txt doesn't exist in lookup up

Answer (score 1):

The code you need is this:

```
For %%F in (%1\*) do (
    If Exist %2\%%~nxF (
        copy %%F %3\%%~nxF
    )   
)
```

So if you save this to a Copy.bat file and call from cmd:

```
Copy.bat C:\a C:\b C:\c
```

the files from folder a that also exist in folder b will be copied in folder c.

Explanation of symbols:

- %%F stores the path of the current file that is parsed from the folder (eg C:\a\a.txt)
- %%~nxF stores only the name of the file (eg a.txt)
- %1 stores the value of your first parameter (eg C:\a)
- %2 stores the value of your second parameter (eg C:\b)
- %3 stores the value of your third parameter (eg C:\c)

For more information about batch commands visit this link: http://ss64.com/nt/

I hope this was helpful :)